# Does Mikrotik 750GL support Openflow 1.4?

Tags: router

I am currently going through the Openflow 1.4 specification and I was wondering if anyone tried implementing it on a Mikrotik 750GL Routerboard.

Answer (score 1):

Mikrotik has a [wiki page about their Openflow support](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual%3aOpenFlow). Based on the current information on that page they only support Openflow 1.0.